# How can I tell a function to work depending the tab the user is on?

Tags: python, tkinter

#### Tab code

```py
style=ttk.Style()
style.configure("TNotebook", background="#00ff7d") 
style.configure("TFrame", background="#2a2a2a")
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(window)
nb = ttk.Notebook(window)
tabs = tab_control

tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)

tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill='both')

tab_control.add(tab2, text="Untitled Horitzontal File")
```

#### Functions code

```py
def changethemeB():
    textbox.configure(bg="black", fg="white",insertbackground='white')
    my_frame.configure(bg="white")

def changethemeW():
    textbox.configure(bg="white", fg="black",insertbackground='black')
    my_frame.configure(bg="black")
```

#### Question

How can I tell the `changetheme` functions to change the theme depending on what tab I am?

Answer (score 0):

Bind `<<NotebookTabChanged>>` to a function. Add your tab names as key and function reference as values in a dictionary. `.tab(tab.select(), "text")`  will return current tab's text use this to call the function.

example code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def tabchange(event):
    themes[tab.tab(tab.select(), "text")]()

def fun1():
    print("Theme 1")
    text.configure(bg="white", fg="black",insertbackground='black')

def fun2():
    print("Theme 2")
    text.configure(bg="black", fg="white",insertbackground='white')
    
root = Tk()

tab = ttk.Notebook(root)
tab.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", tabchange)
  
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab)

  
tab.add(tab1, text ='Tab 1')
tab.add(tab2, text ='Tab 2')
tab.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both")

text = Text(root)
text.pack()

themes = {"Tab 1": fun1, "Tab 2": fun2}

mainloop()
```